# Combine Files with similar names

Tags: files

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have the following set of files:

lh.aparc.DKTatlas40.stats
lh.BA.stats
lh.curv.stats
lh.w-g.pct.stats
rh.aparc.DKTatlas40.stats
rh.BA.stats
rh.curv.stats
rh.w-g.pct.stats
lh.aparc.a2009s.stats
lh.aparc.stats
lh.BA.thresh.stats
lh.entorhinal_exvivo.stats
rh.aparc.a2009s.stats
rh.aparc.stats
rh.BA.thresh.stats
rh.entorhinal_exvivo.stats

I want to combine each 'rh' file with each 'lh' file
For example I need to combine 
lh.aparc.DKTatlas40.stats + rh.aparc.DKTatlas40.stats = merge.aparc.DKTatlas40.stats

How do I do it?

Comment: There is a 'rh' for each 'lh'
They are basically values for left side and right side of the brain.......
so the measures inside the files are also same ......just that they are separated in left and right ......

Comment: You can't accept an answer and then change the question... Well you can, but it invalidates the given answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for lh in lh*; do
    cat "$lh" "rh${lh#lh}" >"merge${lh#lh}"
done
```

This will concatenate each `lh` file with the corresponding `rh` file and save the concatenated version as `merge` (followed by whatever comes after `lh` in the filename).

The parameter expansion `${lh#lh}` will remove the string `lh` from the start of the value of `$lh` (e.g. turn `lh.BA.stats` into `.BA.stats`).

Comment: Thanks I did!

My issue now is that the columns are repeating?How do I solve this?

Comment: @ShreyaChakrabarti Do you mean that you have duplicates in the contents of the concatenated files? We don't know anything about the contents of those files. You'd better submit a new question about that.

Answer (score 0):

Since your files are paired, you can loop through one and intuit the name of the other:

```
for f in lh.*; do
    cat "$f" "${f/lh/rh}" > "${f/lh/merge}"
done
```

The above loop will create a `merge.*.stats` file for each lh/rh pair.

The construct `${var/foo/bar}` will replace the first instance of `foo` in the variable `var` with `bar`; we do this first to intuit the name of the paired file, and then to define the filename for the merged result of the concatenation.